# Taxonomy and Search

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have a book in Drupal with 17 chapters, and several subchapters within them. I want to set up a filtered search that will let me restrict a search entry to only a specified chapter. I've labeled the chapters with a taxonomy vocabulary and using the custom search module, I have set up a search that lets you filter by taxonomy.

However, when I do this, the search doesn't work for the child pages associated with a chapter. For example, in using my method and searching chapter 1, I don't get any results from the subchapters in chapter 1. Is there a way to resolve this? Or do I have to set up my search in a different way?

Answer (score 0):

You should change your filter to 'Has taxonomy terms (with depth)'

This will also include the child entities, or sub chapters in your situation.

Comment: How would I enable this setting?